# How to find number of zeroes of an function in an specified interval?

Tags: calculus, rolles-theorem

I am lot confused about this section.

> I have studied Rolle's theroem by which i can find whether a function cuts x axis at least one time in a given interval or not.

Coming up later I found question which are asking for more than one zeroes of a function in an interval

My point is that:

> is there any generalized approach to tackle such problems to find exactly how many number of times a function cuts the x-axis in an given interval?

Comment: For polynomials, you can use the sturm-chain.

Comment: Yeah i have searched this concept but i am unable to understand how this concept really works.

Comment: Please tell us what's the question that you mentioned.

Comment: I am not asking about a specific question. I just want to know a general approach for such problems